# UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:[update]

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

````
- ```
````

import tensorflow as tf from tensorflow.keras.layers import Densemodel1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
```

```
  # Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer

  model1.add(Dense(units = 15,
  input_shape = (X_train.shape\[1\],),
  kernel_initializer = 'uniform',
  activation = 'relu',
  input_dim = 15))

  ### Adding the second hidden layer

  model1.add(Dense(units = 50, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

  # Adding the output layer

  model1.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

  # Compiling the ANN

  model1.compile(optimizer = Adam,
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  metrics = accuracy,
  model1.summary()

  # Fitting the ANN to the Training set

  history = model1.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 64, epochs = 10,verbose = 1)

  **i will tray the above code but one error is challenging me how can i solve this **UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:** error**
  Model: "sequential_4"

  _________________________________________________________________

  Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
  =

  dense_12 (Dense)            (None, 15)                15

  dense_13 (Dense)            (None, 50)                800

  dense_14 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 51

  =================================================================
  Total parameters: 866
  Trainable parameters: 866
  Non-trainable params: 0

  _________________________________________________________________

  Epoch 1/10
  -

  UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
  Cell In\[38\], line 21, model1.summary()In \[38
  20 # Fitting the ANN to the Training Set
  \---\> 21 history = model1.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 
  64, epochs = 10,verbose = 1)

  File \~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\utils\\ traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.locals> .error_handler(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
  67     filtered_tb = \_process_traceback_frames(e.traceback)
  68 # To get the full stack trace, call:
  69     # tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()
  \---\> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  71 finally:
  72     del filtered_tb

  File \~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\eager\\execute. py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
  50 try:
  51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
  \---\> 52 tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx.\_handle, device_name, op_name,
  53 inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
  54 except core.\_NotOkStatusException as e.g.,
  55 if name is not None:
```

**UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:**

```
Detected at node 'binary_crossentropy/Cast' defined at (most recent call last:
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3librunpy.py,", line 196, in \_run_module_as_main,
      return \_run_code(code, main_globals, None,
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3librunpy.py,", line 86, in \_run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in module\>
      app.launch_new_instance()
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagestraitletsconfigapplication.py,", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesipykernelkernelapp.py,", line 711, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesTornadoplatformasyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libasynciobase_events.py,", line 603, in run_forever
      self.\_run_once()
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libasynciobase_events.py", line 1906, in \_run_once
      handle.\_run()
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libasyncioevents.py", line 80, in \_run
      self.\_context.run(self.\_callback, \*self.\_args)
      File "C:UsersONE"
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesipykernelkernelbase.py", line 499, in process_one
      await dispatch (\*args)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesipykernelkernelbase.py", line 406, in dispatch_shell
      await result
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesipykernelkernelbase.py,", line 729, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesipykernelipkernel.py", line 411, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesipykernelzmqshell.py", line 531, in run_cell
      return super(). run_cell(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesIPythoncoreinteractiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_cell
      result = self.\_run_cell(
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesIPythoncoreinteractiveshell.py,", line 3016, in \_run_cell
      result = runner (coro)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesIPythoncoreasync_helpers.py,", line 129, in *pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesIPythoncoreinteractiveshell.py", line 3221, in run_cell_async,
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesIPythoncoreinteractiveshell.py,", line 3400, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self. run_code(code, result, async*=asy):
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packagesIPythoncoreinteractiveshell.py", line 3460, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "C:UsersONEAppDataLocalTempipykernel_70761483772519.py", line 21, in module\>
      history = model1.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 64, epochs = 10, verbose = 1);
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskerasutilstraceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskerasenginetraining.py,", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskerasenginetraining.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskerasenginetraining.py,", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskerasenginetraining.py,", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskerasenginetraining.py,", line 1051, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskerasenginetraining.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskerasenginecompile_utils.py,", line 265, in call
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskeraslosses.py,", line 142, in call
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskeraslosses.py", line 268; in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, \*\*self.\_fn_kwargs)
      File "C:UsersONEanaconda3libsite-packageskeraslosses.py", line 2145, in binary_crossentropy,
      y_true = tf.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
      Node: 'binary_crossentropy/Cast'
      Casting string to float is not supported
      \[\[node binary_crossentropy/Cast\]\]. \[Op:\__inference_train_function_2239\]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Please format your question. As of right now, it is illegible.

Comment: Please check if your dataset or labels contain string value. Please convert those string values to 'integer' or 'float' type before putting for model training.